# Handler Function Declaration in React

Tags: javascript, react-native, event-handling

Can someone explain how this syntax works? I'm not even sure what it's called so I've been having a hard time figuring out why it's written this way:

```
  _handleTextChange = (value) => {
    const inputValue = value;
    this.setState(() => ({
      inputValue,
    }));
  }
```

I understand that everything between the first and last curly brace is part of the function definition, but what exactly does this part mean:

```
_handleTextChange = (value) =>
```

Comment: check out [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). In short `_handleTextChange` is a variable holding a refernce to a function that accepts a single argument which is named `value`. If this is inside a class, then `_handleTextChange` is a [class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields)

Comment: off topic, shorter version: `_handleTextChange = inputValue => this.setState({ inputValue })`